# Rails ActiveRecord model has_one twice to the same model with different foreign keys

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

I have model `Offer` with many fields, among which are there are two fields that relate to the same model:

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: offers
#
#  id                   :integer          not null, primary key
#  name                 :string(250)      default(""), not null
#  destination_id       :integer          not null
#  cruise_line_id       :integer          not null
#  ship_id              :integer          not null
#  departure_date       :date             not null
#  departure_port_id    :integer
#  arrival_date         :date             not null
#  arrival_port_id      :integer
```

`departure_port_id` and `arrival_port_id` relate to the same model `Port`, but can be also `NULL`, if no departure or arrival port provided.

How should `Offer` and `Port` models look like in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
class Offer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :departure_port, class_name: "Port", foreign_key: "departure_port_id"
  belongs_to :arrival_port, class_name: "Port", foreign_key: "arrival_port_id"
end

class Port < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :offer
end
```

Comment: Oh, looks like what I need :) Thanx :) But class `Port` should have `has_one :offer` or `has_many :offers`?

Comment: yeah you are probably right `has_many`. Sorry for that, got distracted by your title :)